# Paint component for panel doesn't draw double point values

Tags: java, graphics, double, coordinates, draw

I have coordinate points that I'm trying to draw relative to each other and cannot get the points to show up. That I'm working with. These points don't work:

```
double[][] subjPoints = {{38.81904602050781,-71.00624084472656}, 
{38.81904602050781,-70.29379272460938}, {37.95466232299805,-
70.35797882080078}, {37.9495735168457,-71.03191375732422}};

double[][] clipPoints = {{38.62575820040764,-70.84753473092672}, {38.418853759765625,-71.02689361572266},
{38.21194931912361,-71.2057395294625}, {37.931301169971185,-70.67791159484983},
{38.1382056106132,-70.49975311140243}, {38.34511005125521,-70.32108875708619}};
```

These points do work:

```
double[][] subjPoints = {{50, 150}, {200, 50}, {350, 150}, {350, 300},
    {250, 300}, {200, 250}, {150, 350}, {100, 250}, {100, 200}};

double[][] clipPoints = {{100, 100}, {300, 100}, {300, 300}, {100, 300}};
```

_

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.translate(30, 60);
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);


    drawPolygon(g2, subjPoints, Color.blue);
    drawPolygon(g2, clipPoints, Color.red);


}

private void drawPolygon(Graphics2D g2, List<PointA> points, Color color) {
    g2.setColor(color);
    int len = points.size();
    Line2D line = new Line2D.Double();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        PointA p1 = points.get(i);
        PointA p2 = points.get((i + 1) % len);
        line.setLine(p1.getX(), p1.getY(), 
                p2.getX(), p2.getY());
        g2.draw(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: From a quick glance, all the y-values seem to be negative (smaller than -70). Have you tried not using `g2.translate(30, 60);` but something like `g2.translate(30, 60+70);` or so...?

Comment: thanks, that helped bring it into the frame but since the points are so close together it only shows up as a tiny little dot. Is there any way to zoom in on it?

Comment: You can also do a `g.scale(10,10)` to scale everything by a factor of 10, but note that when you have *multiple* transformations (like translation and scaling), it can become fiddly to get their *order* right. You could also consider transforming the points directly in the input, e.g. compute their bounding box and scale it to fill the screen. Shameless self-promotion: For interactive panning and zooming, you could consider my https://github.com/javagl/Viewer/tree/master/viewer-core library.

Comment: how should I go about making it show up bigger while still being able to view it. It seems that if i scale it to make it bigger it ends up being out of the frame and nothing shows up.

Answer (score 0):

You have a certain set of points in 2D, and want to paint them into a `JPanel`. And the goal is to make sure that the set of points is rendered "properly" in the panel. Here I assume that "properly" means that all the points should be visible, and they should be rendered so that they basically fill the available space.

There are different approaches for this.

The most basic approach would involve the following steps (disregarding some implementation details for now) :

- You have to compute the bounding box of the points
- You have to compute the transform that has to be applied to the points so that they fill the screen. This transform can be computed from the bounding box
- You have to transform the points
- You have to paint the transformed points

In the example code below, these steps are implemented in the `convertToPoints`, `computeBoundingBox`, `computeTransform`, `transformPoints` and `drawPolygon` methods of the `ScaledPaintingPlainPanel` class.

In your case, the points are actually points of a *polygon* - that is, they are connected with lines. This can make things a bit simpler: You can convert the points into a `java.awt.Shape`, so that you don't have to compute the bounding box manually. The shape can also be transformed and painted more easily. This is shown in the `ScaledPaintingPlainPanelSimpler` class.

The results are the same in both cases:

[image: ScaledPainting]

The code is here:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ScaledPaintingPlain
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));

        ScaledPaintingPlainPanel p0 = 
            new ScaledPaintingPlainPanel();
        f.getContentPane().add(p0);

        ScaledPaintingPlainPanelSimpler p1 = 
            new ScaledPaintingPlainPanelSimpler();
        f.getContentPane().add(p1);

        f.setSize(1200, 800);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class ScaledPaintingPlainPanel extends JPanel
{
    double[][] subjPoints =
    {
        { 38.81904602050781, -71.00624084472656 },
        { 38.81904602050781, -70.29379272460938 },
        { 37.95466232299805, -70.35797882080078 },
        { 37.9495735168457, -71.03191375732422 } 
    };

    double[][] clipPoints =
    {
        { 38.62575820040764, -70.84753473092672 },
        { 38.418853759765625, -71.02689361572266 },
        { 38.21194931912361, -71.2057395294625 },
        { 37.931301169971185, -70.67791159484983 },
        { 38.1382056106132, -70.49975311140243 },
        { 38.34511005125521, -70.32108875708619 } 
    };

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
        g2.setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        // Convert the arrays into lists of points
        List<Point2D> sPoints = convertToPoints(subjPoints);
        List<Point2D> cPoints = convertToPoints(clipPoints);

        // Compute the bounding boxes of the point lists
        Rectangle2D sBounds = computeBoundingBox(sPoints);
        Rectangle2D cBounds = computeBoundingBox(cPoints);
        Rectangle2D bounds = new Rectangle2D.Double();
        Rectangle2D.union(sBounds, cBounds, bounds);

        AffineTransform affineTransform = computeTransform(bounds);

        // Transform the points
        transformPoints(sPoints, affineTransform);
        transformPoints(cPoints, affineTransform);

        // Draw the point lists as polygons
        drawPolygon(g2, sPoints, Color.BLUE);
        drawPolygon(g2, cPoints, Color.RED);
    }


    private static List<Point2D> convertToPoints(double array[][])
    {
        List<Point2D> points = new ArrayList<Point2D>();
        for (double a[] : array)
        {
            points.add(new Point2D.Double(a[0], a[1]));
        }
        return points;
    }

    private static Rectangle2D computeBoundingBox(
        Iterable<? extends Point2D> points)
    {
        double minX = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        double minY = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        double maxX = -Double.MAX_VALUE;
        double maxY = -Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Point2D p : points)
        {
            minX = Math.min(minX, p.getX());
            minY = Math.min(minY, p.getY());
            maxX = Math.max(maxX, p.getX());
            maxY = Math.max(maxY, p.getY());
        }
        return new Rectangle2D.Double(minX, minY, maxX - minX,  maxY - minY);
    }

    private AffineTransform computeTransform(Rectangle2D bounds)
    {
        // Compute the scaling factor that has to be applied to the
        // points so that the painting fills the screen
        double scaleX = getWidth() / bounds.getWidth();
        double scaleY = getHeight() / bounds.getHeight();
        double scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);

        // Compute the transform that has to be applied to the
        // points so that they fill the screen
        AffineTransform affineTransform = new AffineTransform();
        affineTransform.scale(scale, scale);
        affineTransform.translate(-bounds.getX(), -bounds.getY());

        return affineTransform;
    }

    private static void transformPoints(
        Iterable<? extends Point2D> points, AffineTransform affineTransform)
    {
        for (Point2D point : points)
        {
            affineTransform.transform(point, point);
        }
    }


    private void drawPolygon(Graphics2D g2, List<Point2D> points, Color color)
    {
        g2.setColor(color);
        int len = points.size();
        Line2D line = new Line2D.Double();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            Point2D p1 = points.get(i);
            Point2D p2 = points.get((i + 1) % len);
            line.setLine(p1.getX(), p1.getY(), p2.getX(), p2.getY());
            g2.draw(line);
        }
    }
}



class ScaledPaintingPlainPanelSimpler extends JPanel
{
    double[][] subjPoints =
    {
        { 38.81904602050781, -71.00624084472656 },
        { 38.81904602050781, -70.29379272460938 },
        { 37.95466232299805, -70.35797882080078 },
        { 37.9495735168457, -71.03191375732422 } 
    };

    double[][] clipPoints =
    {
        { 38.62575820040764, -70.84753473092672 },
        { 38.418853759765625, -71.02689361572266 },
        { 38.21194931912361, -71.2057395294625 },
        { 37.931301169971185, -70.67791159484983 },
        { 38.1382056106132, -70.49975311140243 },
        { 38.34511005125521, -70.32108875708619 } 
    };

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
        g2.setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        // Convert the arrays into shapes
        Shape sShape = convertToShape(subjPoints);
        Shape cShape = convertToShape(clipPoints);

        // Compute the bounding boxes of the shapes
        Rectangle2D sBounds = sShape.getBounds2D();
        Rectangle2D cBounds = cShape.getBounds2D();
        Rectangle2D bounds = new Rectangle2D.Double();
        Rectangle2D.union(sBounds, cBounds, bounds);

        AffineTransform affineTransform = computeTransform(bounds);

        g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2.draw(affineTransform.createTransformedShape(sShape));
        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2.draw(affineTransform.createTransformedShape(cShape));
    }

    private static Shape convertToShape(double array[][])
    {
        Path2D path = new Path2D.Double();
        for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        {
            double a[] = array[i];
            double x = a[0];
            double y = a[1];
            if (i == 0)
            {
                path.moveTo(x, y);
            }
            else
            {
                path.lineTo(x, y);
            }
        }
        path.closePath();
        return path;
    }

    private AffineTransform computeTransform(Rectangle2D bounds)
    {
        // Compute the scaling factor that has to be applied to the
        // points so that the painting fills the screen
        double scaleX = getWidth() / bounds.getWidth();
        double scaleY = getHeight() / bounds.getHeight();
        double scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);

        // Compute the transform that has to be applied to the
        // points so that they fill the screen
        AffineTransform affineTransform = new AffineTransform();
        affineTransform.scale(scale, scale);
        affineTransform.translate(-bounds.getX(), -bounds.getY());

        return affineTransform;
    }
}
```

---

Just for completeness: Here is a similar example, using my [`Viewer` library](https://github.com/javagl/Viewer)

[image: ScaledPainting2]

In this case, you can also translate and zoom the rendered representation using the mouse.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import de.javagl.viewer.Painter;
import de.javagl.viewer.Viewer;

public class ScaledPaintingViewer
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGUI());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Viewer");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        f.getContentPane().add(
            new JLabel("<html>"
                + "Right mouse drags: Translate<br> "
                + "Left mouse drags: Rotate<br>"
                + "Mouse wheel: Zoom uniformly<br>"
                + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; +shift: zoom along x<br>"
                + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; +ctrl: zoom along y<br>"
                + "</html>"),
            BorderLayout.NORTH);

        Viewer viewer = new Viewer();
        ScaledPaintingPainter painter = new ScaledPaintingPainter();
        viewer.addPainter(painter);
        viewer.setDisplayedWorldArea(painter.computeBounds());
        f.getContentPane().add(viewer, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        f.setSize(800,800);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class ScaledPaintingPainter implements Painter
{
    double[][] subjPoints =
    {
        { 38.81904602050781, -71.00624084472656 },
        { 38.81904602050781, -70.29379272460938 },
        { 37.95466232299805, -70.35797882080078 },
        { 37.9495735168457, -71.03191375732422 } 
    };

    double[][] clipPoints =
    {
        { 38.62575820040764, -70.84753473092672 },
        { 38.418853759765625, -71.02689361572266 },
        { 38.21194931912361, -71.2057395294625 },
        { 37.931301169971185, -70.67791159484983 },
        { 38.1382056106132, -70.49975311140243 },
        { 38.34511005125521, -70.32108875708619 } 
    };

    @Override
    public void paint(
        Graphics2D g, AffineTransform worldToScreen, double w, double h)
    {
        // Convert the arrays into shapes
        Shape sShape = convertToShape(subjPoints);
        Shape cShape = convertToShape(clipPoints);

        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.draw(worldToScreen.createTransformedShape(sShape));
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.draw(worldToScreen.createTransformedShape(cShape));
    }

    Rectangle2D computeBounds()
    {
        // Convert the arrays into shapes
        Shape sShape = convertToShape(subjPoints);
        Shape cShape = convertToShape(clipPoints);

        // Compute the bounding boxes of the shapes
        Rectangle2D sBounds = sShape.getBounds2D();
        Rectangle2D cBounds = cShape.getBounds2D();
        Rectangle2D bounds = new Rectangle2D.Double();
        Rectangle2D.union(sBounds, cBounds, bounds);

        return bounds;
    }

    private static Shape convertToShape(double array[][])
    {
        Path2D path = new Path2D.Double();
        for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        {
            double a[] = array[i];
            double x = a[0];
            double y = a[1];
            if (i == 0)
            {
                path.moveTo(x, y);
            }
            else
            {
                path.lineTo(x, y);
            }
        }
        path.closePath();
        return path;
    }

}
```